# Check if a field has value greater than 0 in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a beginner in PHP my SQL & developing a library project.

I'm done with the CRUD operations for the table books which has id, title,, author, class, subject & quantity as its columns.

I've successfully printed the table on one of my pages with the respective values of each & every column using the mysqli_fetch_array() method.

But there's another page for which I wish to display the quantity as availability with either a 'YES' or 'NO' message.

I've tried creating a variable in the fetch loop assigned the value of the quantity field to it. Here's the code -

```
 while($query_exec=mysqli_fetch_array($did_query_exec, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
 {
  $bool = $query_exec['Available'];
  if($bool>0)
  {
      $bool="YES";
  }
  else
  {
      $bool="NO";
  }
      echo "<table><tr><td>'.$bool.'</td></tr></table>";
```

It works now, thanks to all the people who commented.

Comment: Can you show the database data and the query to you used to fetch the data?

Comment: if it is the 5th column shouldnt the index be 4?

Comment: and also if you are referring to the column index, i dont think you need to enclose the number in any quotes, just `$query_exec[4]`

Comment: if($bool>=0)
remove = from condition..

Comment: First of all, thanks you all for the quick response.

Comment: I've just modified the code a bit, changing the fetch method, plz have a look.  This time it prints $bool.

Comment: Never mind, I've solved it correcting the syntax for the $bool inside the <td> tag to <td>'.$bool.'</td>    Thanks all & specially Raman for pointing out the silly logical error I made in the if statement.